# Crop an image by drawing with finger touches

Tags: ios, image, crop, cgcontext, cgpath

I am working on an application wherein the user draws some closed area on an image. I want to crop any closed area drawn on that image. In a way I would like to achieve this functionality in [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cut-me-in-easy-to-use-photo/id556546026?mt=8.)

I have done the drawing part using touches method and CGContext but I am unable to crop the drawn area. Please help me out. i am running out of time for the dead line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a `CGPathRef` that you where able to draw in the `CGContext`.
From there you can create a layer, assign the image as a content and use a `CAShapeLayer` a s a mask to crop it.

```
CGPathRef path;
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[shapeLayer setPath:path];

CALayer *imgLayer = [CALayer layer];
[imgLayer setContents:img];
[imgLayer setMask:shapeLayer];

[self.layer addSublayer:imgLayer];
```

Comment: I am not using CGPathRef, but CGContextBeginPath(ctx);

Comment: can you help to draw using CGPathRef.

Comment: Could you please amend your question posting your code. From here it's quite difficult to help you otherwise