# How to create a mask from an image

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, masking

I have an image in NSbundle. below is the image

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2093tvt&s=5

I want to use this image as mask image and want to apply it on any image so that other image will come in same shape as above images shape.

So its a Duplicate question but its not working for me..

As in above question it was suggested to grascale the image so i did same. i changed the image to grayscale by code

```
- (UIImage *) convertToGreyscale:(UIImage *)i {

int kRed = 1;
int kGreen = 2;
int kBlue = 4;

int colors = kGreen;
int m_width = i.size.width;
int m_height = i.size.height;

uint32_t *rgbImage = (uint32_t *) malloc(m_width * m_height * sizeof(uint32_t));
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rgbImage, m_width, m_height, 8, m_width * 4, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, m_width, m_height), [i CGImage]);
CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

// now convert to grayscale
uint8_t *m_imageData = (uint8_t *) malloc(m_width * m_height);
for(int y = 0; y < m_height; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < m_width; x++) {
        uint32_t rgbPixel=rgbImage[y*m_width+x];
        uint32_t sum=0,count=0;
        if (colors & kRed) {sum += (rgbPixel>>24)&255; count++;}
        if (colors & kGreen) {sum += (rgbPixel>>16)&255; count++;}
        if (colors & kBlue) {sum += (rgbPixel>>8)&255; count++;}
        m_imageData[y*m_width+x]=sum/count;
    }
}
free(rgbImage);

// convert from a gray scale image back into a UIImage
uint8_t *result = (uint8_t *) calloc(m_width * m_height *sizeof(uint32_t), 1);

// process the image back to rgb
for(int i = 0; i < m_height * m_width; i++) {
    result[i*4]=0;
    int val=m_imageData[i];
    result[i*4+1]=val;
    result[i*4+2]=val;
    result[i*4+3]=val;
}

// create a UIImage
colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
context = CGBitmapContextCreate(result, m_width, m_height, 8, m_width * sizeof(uint32_t), colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
UIImage *resultUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
CGImageRelease(image);

free(m_imageData);

// make sure the data will be released by giving it to an autoreleased NSData
[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:result length:m_width * m_height];

return resultUIImage;
}
```

below is the grayscale image

link1:

and when i mask the image then in result i get below result
Link given in comments. i can not add more than 2 links

link2:

I think i have not created proper mask image

I am trying to mask below image
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=10di24m&s=5

Can any one tell the way to make mask image?

Comment: link1: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2nbzme8&s=5#.Ul0OiGT09e4         link2: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=21l52c5&s=5

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crop an image by drawing with finger touches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362718/crop-an-image-by-drawing-with-finger-touches)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the method graysclae that you are using.It makes the color outside the circle as black, but it should be white to mask it properly.

Here is the image category that i have written to

**UIImage+Mask.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (Mask)

- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *) image;
- (UIImage *)greyscaleImage;
@end
```

**UIImage+Mask.m**

```
@implementation UIImage (Mask)


- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *) image
{
    CGImageRef imageReference = image.CGImage;
    CGImageRef maskReference = self.CGImage;

    CGImageRef imageMask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskReference),
                                             CGImageGetHeight(maskReference),
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskReference),
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskReference),
                                             CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskReference),
                                             CGImageGetDataProvider(maskReference),
                                             NULL, // Decode is null
                                             YES // Should interpolate
                                             );

    CGImageRef maskedReference = CGImageCreateWithMask(imageReference, imageMask);
    CGImageRelease(imageMask);

    UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskedReference];
    CGImageRelease(maskedReference);

    return maskedImage;
}

- (UIImage *)greyscaleImage {

    CGImageRef imgRef = self.CGImage;

    // Get the image width
    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

    // Create a Grayscale colour space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

    /*
     * Create the context - based on orientation
     */
    CGContextRef context = nil;

    // If the orientation isn't UIImageOrientationUp then we'll need to rotate
    UIImageOrientation orient = self.imageOrientation;

    switch (orient) {
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:

            context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);
            break;

        default:
            context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, height, width, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);
            break;
    }

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    /*
     * Create a context translation/rotation based on the orientation
     */
    switch(orient) {
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            // 2 = 0th row is at the top, and 0th column is on the right - Flip Horizontal
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMake(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, width, 0.0));
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDown:
            // 3 = 0th row is at the bottom, and 0th column is on the right - Rotate 180 degrees
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMake(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, width, height));
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            // 4 = 0th row is at the bottom, and 0th column is on the left - Flip Vertical
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, 0.0, 0, -1.0, 0.0, height));
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            // 5 = 0th row is on the left, and 0th column is the top - Rotate -90 degrees and Flip Vertical
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMake(0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, height, width));
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            // 6 = 0th row is on the right, and 0th column is the top - Rotate 90 degrees
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMake(0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, width));
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            // 7 = 0th row is on the right, and 0th column is the bottom - Rotate 90 degrees and Flip Vertical
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMake(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
            // 8 = 0th row is on the left, and 0th column is the bottom - Rotate -90 degrees
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMake(0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, height, 0.0));
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationUp:
            // Nothing to do here
            break;
    }

    /*
     * Create the new image
     */
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height));
    //CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, );
    // Draw the image to the context
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);

    // Get a UIImage from the context
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *imageCopy =  [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    // Release
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    return imageCopy;
}

@end
```

**Here is the usage**

```
UIImage *maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"maskimage"];  // in your case the red dot image
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];   // image to mask
maskImage = [maskImage greyscaleImage];
image = [maskImage maskImage:image];
self.imageView.image = image;
```